# WPF Strange line

Tags: wpf

I have this UC:

```
<UserControl
    bla bla bla
    Background="Blue"> 
    <Grid Background="Red"></Grid> 
</UserControl>
```

This UC is bundled in ContentControl. This has a strange effect. The entire ContentControl turns red, except for the lowest pixels. The bottom pixels become purple. If you specify other colors, they also blend. If colors are not specified in either the UC or the Grid, but in the Grid add a completely painted element, then this line still remains and will take the color of that window or control on which UC is located.

This problem appears with any containers (DataPanel, StackPanel, etc.). Has anyone encountered such a problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by setting the `SnapsToDevicePixels` property of the `ControlContent` to `True`

Comment: Set that on your top-level `Window` instead, and it will flow down to everything automatically.  It makes WPF look a lot better.  I'd also recommend setting `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"` there also for better looking font rendering.